# log4j : Logs aren't being updated due to an NameNotFoundException

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using Apache commons logging with log4j for logging Mechanism .
I observered that , the logs aren't being updated or refreshed due to the below exception . 
The below Exception is being printed inside catalina.log
Please let me know how this Exception is linked with Logs being Updated

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name AKADbPool is not bound in this Context
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
        at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:152)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
        at com.scivantage.middleware.util.J2EEUtil.connectToDataSource(J2EEUtil.java:48)
```

Why aren't  my Application  Logs aren't being updated due to above Exception ??

**This is my Log4j.properties file**

```
log4j.rootCategory=Info, A1
# A1 is a DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.file=D:\\Greetings\\Ravk.log
log4j.appender.A1.datePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.append=true
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-22d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is *because* of that exception that you're not seeing logs. It is just a coincidence that you're seeing the exception and the logs aren't working!

See if you have multiple `log4j.properties`, `log4j.xml`s loaded in the classpath. Do not forget to look inside the classes folder and JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

Add

-Dlog4j.debug=true

to your runtime-configuration, to see how log4j is configuring itself during startup..